# non-static data member initializers questions

Tags: c++, c++11

I've built MinGW from trunk-version GCC-4.7.0: http://code.google.com/p/mingw-builds/downloads/list

In the description of changes of this version it is said that non-static data member initializers are implemented: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm

When I try to compile such an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct type {
   type()
      :i(33)
   {}

   int i;
   std::string s("string");
};

int main() {
   type t;
   std::cout << t.i << " : " << t.s << std::endl;
}
```

I get a ton of errors, and this one is in the end:

> main.cpp:16:35: note: 'std::string (type::*)(int) {aka
>   std::basic_string (type::*)(int)}' is not derived from 'const
>   std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>' main.cpp:16:35: note:
>   could not resolve address from overloaded function 't.type::s'

But according to the documentation, the code is correct.

Comment: I have no GCC 4.7 installed to test it and my version doesn't support member initialization, but do you compile it with -std=c++0x flag?

Comment: Note that member initializers are new to GCC 4.7, so it should be a simple compiler bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem seems to be an ambiguity in determining whether you are declaring a function or an object, and the compiler is choosing the function.

You should try initializing the string using this syntax instead:

```
std::string s = "string";
```

If we follow the link from the GCC Release Notes concerning non-static data member initializers ([proposal N2756](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm)), they mention this in problem 1, with this resolution note:

> CWG had a 6-to-3 straw poll in Kona in favor of class-scope lookup;
>   and that is what this paper proposes, with initializers for non-static
>   data members limited to the “= initializer-clause” and “{
>   initializer-list }” forms.

Comment: Does this mean that `std::string s("string");` is a valid function-declaration? Can you explain how i should interpret it?

Comment: Does this also work for constructors that are `explicit`? Either way I’d probably prefer `std::string s{"string"};`.

Comment: @Björn: It's not a valid declaration. If it were a valid function declaration, there would be no compile error.

Answer (score 0):

The data member must be initialized by brace-or-equal-initializers.
Visit http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm

8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]

Change the grammar for initializer:

initializer:

```
= (  expression-list  )
```

brace-or-equal-initializer:

```
=  initializer-clause

   braced-init-list
```